# Why does the CW hat (the Stallman) look like Jesus?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013

I noticed that the [Stallman hat](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/the-stallman) looks like Jesus. Why is that?

[image: Stallman hat]

Comment: Because Richard Stallman has a Jesus looking beard ?

Comment: [everything looks like jesus](http://www.buzzfeed.com/arielknutson/people-who-found-jesus-in-their-food)

Comment: How do you know it's not The Dude?

Comment: Am I the only one that thought this was a special hat made for [jmort253](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155826/jmort253)?

Comment: We need more of This Dude Jesus, on a generational basis. *Please, gwod, don't stop its production*. Thanks, Stallman, for spreading a loving message.

Comment: something something god complex

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Related(image of Stallman):

[image: Is it Jesus?]

As for the actual hat, and not the <strike>potential</strike> resemblance of Jesus, Stallman is actually a pretty cool guy. He is most known for his work with the [GNU project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Project),

> "The GNU Project is a free software, mass collaboration project, announced on 27 September 1983, by Richard Stallman at MIT. Its aim is to give computer users freedom and control in their use of their computers and computing devices, by **collaboratively developing** and providing software that is based on the following freedom rights: users are free to run the software, share it (copy, distribute), study it and modify it"

The emphasis is probably why he is the hat reward for CW editing.

[image]

[What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Comment: EUREKA!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: [Stallman is actually a pretty coolH^H^H^H^ weird guy.](http://youtu.be/I25UeVXrEHQ)

Answer (score 46):

Strictly-speaking, we don't know what Jesus looked like.

We do, however, know what [Richard Stallman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_stallman) looks like. And he has *a pretty groovy head of hair*.

It is possible that Richard Stallman looks like Jesus. He is, after all, the Savior of Software.

Comment: How are we not more sure that Jesus looked like Stallman, in a Mediterranean way?

Answer (score 38):

Nonsense!  There's hardly any resemblance at all!  See for yourself:

**Richard Stallman:**                           **Jesus Christ:**
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 18):

Because Stallman <s>looks like</s> is **open source** Jesus.

[image: An xkcd comic, please see the link for a transcript.]

Comment: [An elaboration of xkcd 225, *Open Source*](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/225:_Open_Source) (for the uninitiated).

Answer (score 12):

According to [religionfacts.com](http://www.religionfacts.com/jesus/image_gallery.htm) "Jesus first appears with a beard in the late 4th century (and then not consistently)"

So, perhaps to put it more accurately, Stallman looks like a guy with long hair and a beard and at some points in history Jesus was depicted with long hair and a beard...

[image]
Christ and the Apostles, Domitilla Catacombs, Rome c.350
[image]
Christ as Teacher, Junius Bassus Tomb c.360

Comment: Hmmm, an inconsistent beard? Sounds like the original designer stubble. Or maybe he just grew it in every year around Christmas to keep his face warm.

Answer (score 8):

Because rms posed for it:

[image: sainted rms]

Comment: I am not going to quibble about mistaking St IGNUcius for Jesus! Nice find!

Comment: For the record, I took this picture. It was in '97 at the IPISA conference in Italy, at a friends house, and we were hosting RMS. He was a lot of fun to hang out with :)

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I think it's a conspiracy by balpha. See how perfectly it fits him!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Of course that is [Saint IGNUcious](https://stallman.org/saint.html) and not Jesus!

[image: St IGNUcious]